# Finetuning Joomla 3.1 Column Layout

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to fix the layout on a Joomla 3.1 installation. I have 3 featured articles. Depending on how I sort them, the 1st spans the entire width of the page like I want. The next 2 are positioned side-by-side which I do not want.

Background: This is and upgrade from 1.5.x to 3.1 using jUpgrade. I have using several different templates including all the default ones, Gantry & Wright with no luck. I've attached screenshots of the layout I'm trying to copy and what's currently being output. So far I have tried adjusting the template layout settings as well as the core Blog/Featured Layout as suggested. I've seen and understand how to fix this issues in Joomla 1.5 but no concrete answers for 3.1 that have worked.

Here is a link to what I want:
http://www.confabbpd.com/images/posts/good.jpg

Here is a link to what I'm getting:
http://www.confabbpd.com/images/posts/bad.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your menu item edit view for "Category Blog" menu type, got to the advanced options tab and select "blog layout options" and set your columns to "1".

Comment: I'm embarrassed to ask a stupid question but is there a general area to edit ALL menu types regardless of the specific menu items that will be assigned to them? If so, I don't believe I have found that area...

Comment: Here is a screenshot of what I have changed but it has not solved the problem: ttp://www.confabbpd.com/images/posts/menu.jpg    I went to Menus > Main Menu > Home

Comment: Go to Content and click on OPtions.  YOu can set the default options there.

Comment: Took awhile but it appears that a menu item that was pulled over in the upgrade was named "Home" and that's what I was editing instead of the actual home.